# Extracting a substring based on second occurence using Java - substringBetween() function

Tags: java, string, apache-commons, apache-stringutils, apache-commons-lang

I have the following string "If this is good and if that is bad". The requirement is to extract the string "that" from the main string.

Using

```
substringBetween(mainString, "If", "is") returns the string "this".
```

Could you please help in extracting the required string in this case. If this is not possible using the function substringBetween(), is there any alternative string function to achieve this?

Comment: may be `substringBetween(mainString, "If", "is bad")` ??

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you get instead?

Comment: This is not my actual string. The actual string is an xml converted to string(there is no possibility to convert it back to xml as it is received from another tool). There are child nodes with repeating information. (Say, multiple flight segments within a travel segment). Hence the question.

Comment: If it's xml you should use an xml parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` and `Pattern` matching to extract it, e.g.:

```
String s = "If this is good and if that is bad";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("if(.*?)is");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
}
```

Comment: I did try the above,
String s = "If this is good and If that is bad";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("if(.*?)is");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
}
The output i get is "this" not "that". Any idea how to modify this so that it will return an array or a list of all elements that satisfy the regex?

Comment: @VidyaShankarNS Instead if using `if(m.find()){`try using `while(m.find()){`, it will print all the matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding my problem. This was what I wanted. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

you mean  `StringUtils.substringBetween(foo, "if", "is")` instead  of
`StringUtils.substringBetween(foo, "If", "is")` because the method substringBetween is case sensitive operation
[image]

and searching between "If" and "is" is not the same result as between "if" and "is"

```
String foo = "If this is good and if that is bad";
String bar = StringUtils.substringBetween(foo, "if", "is");
// String bar = StringUtils.substringBetween(foo, "If", "is");
System.out.println(bar);
```

Comment: My bad, I will provide a better mainString to illustrate. Consider String foo = "and If this is good and If that is good". I need to extract "that" by giving only the immediate predecessor and successor as the inputs in substringBetween()